# Limit of $(3n+1)^{1/n}$

Tags: limits

I am working through a question that requires me to prove that a certain limit tends to 1. I have reached an endpoint where I have:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} (3n+1)^{1/n}$$

I know that and can use the fact that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}( n^{1/n}) = 1$

However, I am not sure if I can just use this fact to say that it applies for $(3n+1)^{1/n} $ and I also am stuck on proving it.

Comment: Hint $$3n\le 3n+1\le 3n+n.$$ Also, I have seen many similar question of this form here.

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

$(3n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}} =e^{\frac{1}{n}ln(3n+1)}=e^{\frac{1}{n}ln(n(3+\frac{1}{n} )) }=e^{\frac{1}{n}ln(n) +\frac{1} {n} ln(3+\frac{1}{n} )}$

So :

$\lim_{n\to+\infty} (3n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to+\infty} e^{\frac{1}{n}ln(n) +\frac{1} {n} ln(3+\frac{1}{n} )}=1$

Because

$\lim_{n\to+\infty} \frac{ln(n)}{n} =0$

And

$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{1} {n}ln(3+\frac{1}{n} ) =0$

Answer (score 0):

As a hint you apply $\ln$ to both sides of limit.

As a second hint rewrite like below
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} (3n+1)^{1/n}=\\\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{3n+1}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{3}\sqrt[n]{n+\frac13}=\\
\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{3}\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n+\frac13}=1\times1$$

Answer (score 0):

Per the hint in comments, we squeeze the limit expression between $(3n)^{1/n}$ and $(4n)^{1/n}$, both of which evaluate to $1$, so the limit is $1$. (It's easier to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a^{1/n}=1$ for $a\ge1$.)

Answer (score 0):

We can use that

$$1=(1)^{1/n}\le (3n+1)^{1/n}\le (4n)^{1/n}=4^\frac1n \cdot n^\frac1n$$

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_{n\to \infty} (3n+1)^{1/n}$$
Apply D'Alembert-Cauchy criterion:
$$L=\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac {3n+4}{3n+1}$$
$$\implies L=1$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (3n+1)^{1/n}  
    &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \exp \left( \ln \left( (3n+1)^{1/n} \right) \right)  \\
    &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \exp \left( \frac{1}{n} \ln \left( 3n+1 \right) \right)  \\
    &= \exp \left( \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{\ln \left( 3n+1 \right)}{n} \right)  \\
    &= \exp \left( \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{\ln \left( 3n \left( 1 + \frac{1}{3n} \right) \right)}{n} \right)  \\
    &= \exp \left( \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{\ln (3) + \ln (n) + \ln \left( 1 + \frac{1}{3n}  \right)}{n} \right)  \\
    &\overset{?_1}= \exp \left( \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{\ln (3)}{n} + \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln (n)}{n} + \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln \left( 1 + \frac{1}{3n}  \right)}{n} \right)  \\
    &= \exp \left( 0 + \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln n^{1/n} + \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln \left( 1 + \frac{1}{3n}  \right)}{n} \right)  \\
    &\overset{?_2}= \exp \left( \ln \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n^{1/n} + \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln \left( 1 + \frac{1}{3n}  \right)}{n} \right)  \\
    &= \exp \left( \ln 1 + \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln \left( 1 + \frac{1}{3n}  \right)}{n} \right)  \\
    &\overset{?_3}= \exp \left( 0 + \frac{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \ln \left( 1 + \frac{1}{3n}  \right)}{n} \right)  \\
    &\overset{?_4}= \exp \left( \frac{ \ln \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{3n}  \right)}{n} \right)  \\
    &\overset{?_5}= \exp \left( \frac{ \ln \left( \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1 + \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{3n} \right) }{n} \right)  \\
    &= \exp \left( \frac{ \ln \left( 1 + 0 \right) }{n} \right)  \\
    &= \exp \left( \frac{ \ln 1 }{n} \right)  \\
    &= \exp \left( \frac{ 0 }{n} \right)  \\
    &= \exp \left(0 \right)  \\
    &= 1  \text{.}
\end{align*}

We use the continuity of the exponential on its domain without further comment.

- $?_1$ : The limit of a sum is a sum of the limits if those limits exist.  We subsequently show that they do, so this equality is valid.
- $?_2$ : The logarithm is continuous on its domain, so this equality holds if the new limit is in $(0,\infty)$.  It is $1$, so this equality is valid.
- $?_3$ : Again w exchange the limit and the logarithm.  Again, the new limit is in $(0,\infty)$, so this equality is valid.
- $?_4$ : Division is continuous in its numerator without any restriction on domain, so this equality is valid.  (Notice that the domain of the denominator *is* restricted, so there can be something to check here.)
- $?_5$ : The limit of a sum is the sum of the limits, if those limits exist.  As we subsequently show, those limits do exist, so this equality is valid.